# Xcode 4.0.2 Crashes on launch

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos

Xcode crashes on launch, and I do not have any idea why. I downloaded 4.0.2 + iOS SDK (4.3) and installed it. Then I tried to open it and it crashed on launch... Here is my console log that relates to the crash

```
enter cdyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSymbolication.framework/Versions/A/CoreSymbolication 6/14/11 6:10:55 PM  [0x0-0x287287].com.apple.dt.Xcode[18402]
  Referenced from: /iPhoneSDK/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/../../../../Library/PrivateFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/DVTFoundation  6/14/11 6:10:55 PM  [0x0-0x287287].com.apple.dt.Xcode[18402]
  Reason: image not found   6/14/11 6:10:55 PM  [0x0-0x287287].com.apple.dt.Xcode[18402]
catch_mach_exception_raise_state_identity(): PID: 18405 thread: 0x16c77 type: 0xa code: 0x1000f7044 codeCnt: 0x2 flavor: 0x1000f7054 old_state: 0x1000f705c old_stateCnt: 0x2c new_state: 0x1000f802c new_stateCnt: 0x1000f8028 6/14/11 6:10:55 PM  com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[167]
(com.apple.ReportCrash.Self[18405]) Job appears to have crashed: Trace/BPT trap 6/14/11 6:10:55 PM  com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[167]
catch_mach_exception_raise_state_identity(): PID: 18404 thread: 0x17037 type: 0xa code: 0x7fff5fbfdf14 codeCnt: 0x2 flavor: 0x7fff5fbfdf24 old_state: 0x7fff5fbfdf2c old_stateCnt: 0x2c new_state: 0x7fff5fbfe43c new_stateCnt: 0x7fff5fbfe438  6/14/11 6:10:55 PM  com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[167]
(com.apple.ReportCrash[18404]) Job appears to have crashed: Trace/BPT trap  6/14/11 6:10:55 PM  com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[167]
catch_mach_exception_raise_state_identity(): PID: 18402 thread: 0x1703b type: 0xa code: 0x7fff5fbfdf14 codeCnt: 0x2 flavor: 0x7fff5fbfdf24 old_state: 0x7fff5fbfdf2c old_stateCnt: 0x2c new_state: 0x7fff5fbfe43c new_stateCnt: 0x7fff5fbfe438  6/14/11 6:10:55 PM  com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[167]
([0x0-0x287287].com.apple.dt.Xcode[18402]) Job appears to have crashed: Trace/BPT trap  6/14/11 6:10:55 PM  com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[167]ode here
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like `CoreSymbolication` does not exist on your machine. I would uninstall and reinstall.

Comment: You can run `sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools` to remove your current XCode. The description of the script says: "Remove relocatable Xcode Tools or Developer installation so a subsequent installation of a newer developer tools release will work correctly."

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with two Xcode versions which both failed to start.

I initially had Xcode 4.0.1 (back then the world was still a good place).

I wanted to see how our App looks when compiled with the current iOS SDK 5.0

1. So I installed Xcode 4.2 on top of Xcode 4.0.1 (overriding it completely)
2. I tested some stuff in my app and realized that I need to fallback to Xcode < 4.2
3. I installed Xcode 4.1. During the installation process the installer told me that the current installation would move from `/Developer` to `/Developer-4.2`
4. After all this neither of installed Xcode versions worked anymore which is bad.

I decided to uninstall Xcode 4.2 first and then reinstall Xcode 4.1 again.

1. I uninstalled Xcode 4.2 with the command `sudo /Developer-4.2/Library/uninstall-devtools`
2. I run the Xcode 4.1 installer again from `/Applications/Install Xcode.app`
3. After the installation Xcode 4.1 opened so it worked again...

Comment: Same situation. Also decided to reinstall 4.2 as well after, and that seemed to work. Unfortunately, I can't return to the world when it was a better place because of other iOS 5 issues. I guess I'm stuck having 1 foot on the boat and one on the dock.

Comment: @Vinnie Well, for the moment it was fine for us to use  the sdk v4.1 (We had an internal release before the weekend and I did not want to face the problems right at that moment :) ). However, sooner or later we will have to upgrade anyway and I guess the sooner we do this the better. With Apple there is usually no way around the new stuff and I guess that's a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

I reinstalled via `sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools` and the App Store

But the offending source was restored, so Xcode crashed again. Boo!

I renamed the offending source's folder so Xcode couldn't find it.

Xcode couldn't find the source, and never crashed, which allowed me to get back to work.

Extremely Obvious Feature Request to Apple: hold 'option' to suppress previous projects from loading, plus a command line to do the same.

Comment: In the time since posting above, I've realized that another solution would be simply to go to "System Preferences" ->  "General" then just  uncheck "Restore windows when quitting and re-opening apps".