# Crash on xcode 5.0.2 while starting

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, ios7, xcode5

I just downloaded xcode 5.0.2 and while opening initially the Open Project Screen came. Then i closed xcode and after that i tried to start it but it was crashing straight away. I found out the following logs on Console App

```
21/11/13 7:56:41.000 pm kernel[0]: CODE SIGNING: cs_invalid_page(0x7fff946ac000): p=2190[Xcode] final status 0x1000200, denying page sending SIGKILL
21/11/13 7:56:41.000 pm kernel[0]: CODESIGNING: vm_fault_enter(0x7fff946ac000): page 0xffffff80103b61d8 obj 0xffffff802b7a17a0 off 0x10aad000 *** INVALID PAGE ***
21/11/13 7:56:41.806 pm ReportCrash[2193]: Trying to extract VM information using cr2
21/11/13 7:56:41.855 pm com.apple.launchd.peruser.503[476]: (com.apple.dt.Xcode.72720[2190]) Exited: Killed: 9
21/11/13 7:56:42.286 pm ReportCrash[2193]: Saved crash report for Xcode[2190] version 5.0.2 (3335.32) to /Users/arpit/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Xcode_2013-11-21-195642_Aruns-MacBook-Pro.crash
21/11/13 7:56:42.289 pm ReportCrash[2193]: Removing excessive log: file:///Users/arpit/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Xcode_2013-11-21-183407_Aruns-MacBook-Pro.crash
```

Any help regarding this?

I also found this link regarding the same issue

https://discussions.apple.com/message/23562146#23562146

Comment: That log isn't helpful; please post the Xcode crash log, which might be marginally more useful.

Comment: how to get that when xcode isnteven starting,i have provided a link it is the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Is your previous version of Xcode synced to any version control such as git hub or svn ?
Is you open the project it will ask for upgrade just upgrade it you will not get the issue again.Give a try same happened to me as well i tried the same.

you can also refer the link for the same in Xcode 4.2

> [Xcode 4.0.2 Crashes on launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6350756/xcode-4-0-2-crashes-on-launch?rq=1)

Comment: no it wasn't linked to any version control, i just restarted my mac and then tried to open a simple project instead of directly clicking on xcode app and it started fine. Thnks for your valuable time :)